# Indikativ oder Konjunktiv? »So tun, als ob es regne(t(e))«

Tags: subjunctive

In den Buchhandlungen steht seit wenigen Monaten ein neues Buch von Iris Wolff in den Regalen. Es trägt den Titel:

> So tun, als ob es regnet

([Buchbeschreibung](http://www.omvs.at/de/buecher/so-tun-als-ob-es-regnet-1754/))

Mir ist klar, dass für Buchtitel größere sprachliche Freiheiten bestehen als für Sätze in gewöhnlichen Textsorten. Mich würde aber sehr interessieren, was wäre, wenn man aus dem Buchtitel z.B. diesen Satz machen würde:

> Ich werde so tun, als ob es regnet.

Ist dieser Satz grammatisch korrekt? Ich glaube nämlich nicht, dass auf »*als ob*« ein Indikativ folgen kann. Ich würde hier den Konjunktiv I oder eine Ersatzkonstruktion mit *würde* verwenden:

> Ich werde so tun, als ob es regne.
>   Ich werde so tun, als ob es regnen würde.

Auch den Konjunktiv II halte ich für richtig:

> Ich werde so tun, als ob es regnete.

Comment: Ja, ich denke du hast es vollkommen richtig beschrieben!

Comment: Ich bin derselben Meinung wie jacmeird. Außerdem ist es laut Canoo.net (hier: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Komparativsatz.html) **sehr selten** und  **in der gesprochenen Sprache** und **nicht bei *als* mit Verb an erster Stelle** einen Indikativ zu verwenden.

Comment: An sich gehört in einen irrealen Vergleichssatz Konkunktiv II - Was auch mit deinem *so tun, als ob es regnen würde* zum Ausdruck kommt: *... so tun, als ob es **regnete***. Konjunktiv I ist zwar auch richtig, aber bei weitem nicht so gebräuchlich.

Comment: "So tun als ob es regnen würde" mag zwar in der Alltagssprache (vieler Leute) gebräuchlich sein, ist jedoch für korrekten schriftlichen Ausdruck nicht akzeptabel. Anders gesagt: Ein Jungjournalist, der dies in seinem Zeitungsartikel schriebe, bekäme es von seinem Redakteur herausgestrichen. Oder auch: Würde ein Jungredakteur dies schreiben, bekäme er es herausgestrichen.

Comment: @tofro: Danke! Auf den Konjunktiv II habe ich total vergessen. Ich habe meine Frage entsprechend editiert.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Das kommt sehr darauf an, bei welcher Zeitung der Jungredakteur arbeitet. Ich kenne Zeitungen, bei denen ich davon überzeugt bin, dass der Chefredakteur den Konjunktiv herausstreichen und durch eine würde-Konstruktion ersetzen würde.

Comment: Hallo Hubert. Ja. Ich sprach von *guten* Zeitungen.  - Scherz beseite: Darf ich fragen, welche Zeitung du konkret im Sinne hast? Ich kann mir das ehrlich gesagt schwer vorstellen, aber es gibt ja vieles auf der Welt...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich meine die in Wien sehr verbreiteten Gratis-U-Bahn-Zeitungen *Heute* und *Österreich*, die vor allem aus vielen Bildern, großen Überschriften und sehr viel Werbung bestehen. Bei der Einführung der Tageszeitung *Österreich* vor wenigen Jahren kursierte der Witz, dass in dieser Zeitung ausschließlich ausgemusterte Artikel aus anderen Tageszeitungen recycelt würden.

Comment: Hallo Hubert. Interessant. Danke. Aber das bestätigt vielleicht meine These? - Nicht überall wo Zeitung draufsteht, ist auch Zeitung drin. - In Deutschland wird derzeit von berufener Seite die sogenannte "einfache Sprache" beworben, eine Sprachform, die angeblich von Leuten mit kognitiven Einschränkungen besser verstanden wird. Auch hier werden dann die eleganteren Konjunktive weggelassen, und übrigens sogar der Genitiv in toto. Da ist Wien dann "die Hauptstadt von dem Land Österreich".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bei Sätzen mit *als ob* handelt es sich um irreale Vergleichssätze. Dabei äußert der Hauptsatz eine reale Feststellung und steht in der Regel im Indikativ:

> Ich werde so tun, ...

Der Nebensatz, der den irrealen Vergleich angibt, steht hingegen immer im **Konjunktiv II**:

> ... als ob es regnete.

Er kann ersatzweise auch mit *würde* formuliert werden:

> ... als ob es regnen würde.

Der Konjunktiv I hat gar nicht die Funktion, etwas irreales anzuzeigen. Daher wäre "*... als ob es regne*" nicht korrekt.